# How to edit Hiperlink on Flutter_linkify

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to use Flutter Linkify to show a webpage. The link I am planning to use is long (and non-esthetic). I would like to edit the link, for example I want for the screen to read 'Privacy Policy' while the link being 'https://www.long.web/address/.../'

Has anyone done something similar?

```js
SelectableLinkify(
            onOpen: (link) async {
              if (await canLaunch(link.url)) {
                await launch(link.url);
              } else {
                throw 'Could not launch $link';
              }
            },
            text: "Terms of use: https://www.long.web/.../...",
            style: Sizes.style2,
            linkStyle: Sizes.styleLink,
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this, in case anyone needs it.

```html
Container(
             width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 75,
             child: RichText(
                 text: TextSpan(
                   children: [
                     TextSpan(
                       text: 'I accept the ',
                       style: Sizes.style2,
                     ),
                     TextSpan(
                       style: Sizes.styleLink,
                       text: 'Terms of Use',
                       recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                         ..onTap = () async {
                           final url = 'web where doc is hosted';
                           if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                             await launch(
                               url,
                               forceSafariVC: false,
                             );
                           }
                         },
                     ),
                     TextSpan(
                       text: ' and ',
                       style: Sizes.style2,
                     ),
                     TextSpan(
                       style: Sizes.styleLink,
                       text: 'Privacy Policy',
                       recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                         ..onTap = () async {
                           final url = 'web where doc is hosted';
                           if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                             await launch(
                               url,
                               forceSafariVC: false,
                             );
                           }
                         },
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
             ),
           )
```

All you have to do is add your own webpage so the link opens it, we just used the same page where our privacy policy is so users could access it.